# Javascript Drop Down Box

Tags: javascript, php, html, client-side, jquery-events

I am creating a register page for a website and coded in a drop down box that tells users why a birthday us required. For some reason, my code is not working.

Here is the code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function toggleSlideBox(x) {
        if ($('#'+x).is(":hidden")) {
            $('#'+x).slideDown(300);
        } else {
            $('#'+x).slideUp(300);
        }
}
</script>
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<a href="#" class="mouseover" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:toggleSlideBox('why');">why?</a>
          <div id="why" style="background-color:#E6F5FF; border:#999 1px solid; padding:12px; display:none; margin-top:8px;"> Sometime down the road we may offer content that is only suitable for people over 18. We require this information to check your age. <br />
            <br />
            We can also use this information to alert your friends to when your birthday is. </div>
```

Comment: "For some reason, my code is not working." What exactly is not working?

Comment: The Box is not coming down. I took this code from an example website.

Comment: You shouldn't add `javascript:` at the beginning of `onmousedown`. That's a javascript event, so of course it will be handled with javascript. And you could use `href="javascript:toggleSlideBox('why')"` instead of `href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="toggleSlideBox('why');"`

Comment: By the way, you could use [`slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) in your `toggleSlideBox` function instead of your `if / else`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you placing the script below the location of the `<a>`?  If not, you need to make sure that the `a` tag is loaded before your script begins.  Try adding this to your script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function toggleSlideBox(x) {

  $(document).ready(function(){      // ADD THIS

    if ($('#'+x).is(":hidden")) {
            $('#'+x).slideDown(300);
        } else {
            $('#'+x).slideUp(300);
        }
    }

  });                                // ADD THIS

</script>
```

### Also ensure that you have included the jQuery library before you run the script...

Comment: I guess it's not necessarily a given that jQuery was included at the top of the page if he nabbed the script from a site.  Adding that.